# How to set validation in VB6

Tags: vb6

I need the code to set a restriction from allowing a user to save empty ID & USERNAME  in a text box as id lo-gin in a required filed?

Comment: You should at least try to write some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify it on validation;

```
Private sub Validate_Click()

// verify username
If trim(Username.text) = "" then
   Msgbox ("Please enter a username.")
   Username.focus()
   End sub
end if

// Verify password 
If trim(pwd.text) = "" then
   Msgbox ("Please enter a password.")
   pwd.focus()
   End sub
end if

-- Your codes

End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
   if trim(text1.text) ="" then
    'message here
    text1.setfocus
    end if
```